# Getting error in Console that doesn't appear in CMD

Tags: command-line, console, cmd.exe

Running Console (just a wrapper for CMD.exe right?), I am not able to run some of my scripts. Is there a way around this? I would rather use Console if possible, because it's nicer.

here is an example

```
randfuncgen.py -k 2 > z2test
```

This works as intended on plain CMD.exe
Using Console, I get the following error, and z2test is an empty file

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Comment: Is the `path` reported while in CMD the same `path` reported while in Console?

Comment: Python was just installed? Try to logoff/logon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/console/bugs/424/) and as yet there is no answer, although superuser users may prove otherwise. I think the [Console bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/console/bugs/) might be a good place to watch for progress.

Comment: What did you google to find this? Thanks :)

Comment: Projects hosted on Sourceforge have a bug tracker by default, so that was the first place I looked!